# java streams: elegant way to filter according an exception is thrown

Tags: java, java-8, exception, java-stream

Is there any more elegant way to filter according if an exception is thrown?

I mean, currently my code looks like:

```
stream.filter(item -> {
    try {
        validator.with(reference)
            .hasAccess(this.authzManager)
            .isOwner();
        } catch (EspaiDocFault | DataAccessException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
)
```

What I'm trying to do is if an exception is thrown current item stream has to be filtered.

I'm looking for any existing util class or something similar...

Comment: It would be more elegant if you called different methods that return false (or an empty Optional that you can chain to the next call with `map`) instead of throwing these exceptions.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner No, Ican't change these methods

Comment: And what about the element of the stream (`item`) not being used inside the `filter` predicate?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner and the return value of `isOwner` is completely ignored....

Comment: @Aomine Yes, but I think (with a little bit of imagination) that might be on purpose, i.e. if OP just wanted the absense or presence of the exception as a side-effect to check if everything is alright... Who knows? Seems like a bad design anyway...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Now that you mention it makes more sense now but still the answer to your previous question should be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common approach I've seen in many variations is to write own functional interface that will allow a checked exception to be thrown (1) and to adapt that solution to a built-in interface (2).

```
/**
 * An EPredicate is a Predicate that allows a checked exception to be thrown.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of the input to the predicate
 * @param <E> the allowed exception
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface EPredicate<T, E extends Exception> {

    /**
     * (1) the method permits a checked exception
     */
    boolean test(T t) throws E;

    /**
     * (2) the method adapts an EPredicate to a Predicate.
     */
    static <T, E extends Exception> Predicate<T> unwrap(EPredicate<T, E> predicate) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                return predicate.test(t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

An example looks quite elegant:

```
.stream()
.filter(EPredicate.<ItemType, Exception>unwrap(item -> validator.[...].isOwner()))
```

where,

- `ItemType` is the type of `item`;
- `Exception` is a common parent of `EspaiDocFault` and `DataAccessException`.

---

```
.stream()
.filter(EPredicate.unwrap(item -> validator.[...].isOwner()))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) library has a `Try` class that can do what you want:

```
stream.filter(item -> Try.of(() -> validator.with(reference)
                .hasAccess(this.authzManager)
                .isOwner()).getOrElse(false))
```

**Edit**: if you actually want to know whether the exception was thrown or not, Vavr can do that too:

```
stream.filter(item -> Try.of([...]).isSuccess())
```

Alternatively, wrap the whole thing in a method:

```
stream.filter(this::getMyBooleanWithinMyTry)
```